# Double Commander starts always on seconde screen at double screen environment

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am Using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with two screens and installed the filemanager Double Commander. So far no problems, but the Double Commander starts always on the second screen, which I usually don't switch on. Moving the DC Window to the first screen works, but after rebooting the DC Window starts on the second screen again. What can I do to start DC always on first screen?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 20.04.3, you're well behind on applying security fixes so I hope you keep your system offline. [This will show the ISO release of 20.04.4](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) which was over a year ago, but installed systems upgraded to 20.04.4 before that date, with upgraded systems now reporting themselves as 20.04.6.  Are your details correct?  if so upgrade asap!!  or maybe you're using Ubuntu 22.04.3 (it's ISO release is this Thursday & installed systems only recently upgraded to it!) if so please correct your question.